# crear excel en java mediante consulta en MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, excel

estoy tratando de crear un archivo de excel mediante una consulta de mysql,
lo que sucede es lo siguiente hago la consulta de sql con los datos que necesito para hacer unas sumas y diviciones entonces agrego todos esos resultados a un arraylist lo que no se es como hacer para sacar cada  uno de esos datos para ingresarlo en las celdas correspondientes

```
try {
 List listaFinal = new ArrayList();
 List listaCabeceras = new ArrayList();
 con = new Conexion();
 query = "SELECT    Nro_Documento,Nombres,Horas_registradas_en_jira,Proyecto,Horas_laboradas_sin_extras_y_sin_novedades FROM tbljira ORDER BY Proyecto";
 st = con.getConn().prepareStatement(query);

 res = st.executeQuery();

 while (res.next()) {
  TablaJira j = new TablaJira();
  j.setNro_Documento(res.getString("Nro_Documento"));
  j.setNombres(res.getString("Nombres"));
  j.setHoras_registradas_en_jira(res.getDouble("Horas_registradas_en_jira"));
  j.setProyecto(res.getString("proyecto"));
  j.setHoras_laboradas_sin_extras_sin_novedades(res.getDouble("Horas_laboradas_sin_extras_y_sin_novedades"));
  Jira.add(j);

 }
 List fila = null;
 for (int j = 0; j < Jira.size(); j++) {


  String ide = Jira.get(j).getNro_Documento();
  String name = Jira.get(j).getNombres();
  Double h = Jira.get(j).getHoras_registradas_en_jira();
  String proyec = Jira.get(j).getProyecto();
  Double time = Jira.get(j).getHoras_laboradas_sin_extras_sin_novedades();

  if (j == 0) {
   idean = ide;
   nombrean = name;
   timea = h;
   proan = proyec;

  } else if (ide.equals(idean) & proyec.equals(proan)) {

   suma = suma + h + timea;
   idean = ide;

   nombrean = name;
   timea = 0.0;
   horat = time;
  } else {

   idean = ide;
   total = suma / time;
   det.setTiempo_dedicado(total);
   det.setHoras_laboradas(horat);
   det.setNombre_empleado(nombrean);
   det.setNro_Documento(idean);
   det.setHoras_dedicadas(suma);
   det.setNombre_proyecto(proan);


   idean = ide;
   proan = proyec;
   timea = h;
   suma = 0.0;
   lst.add(det);
  }
  if (j + 1 == Jira.size()) {
   if (ide.equals(idean) & proyec.equals(proan)) {

    //suma = suma + h + timea;
    // idean = ide;
    // timea = 0.0;
    total = suma / time;
    det.setNombre_proyecto(proan);
    det.setTiempo_dedicado(total);
    det.setHoras_laboradas(horat);
    det.setNombre_empleado(nombrean);
    det.setNro_Documento(idean);
    det.setHoras_dedicadas(suma);
    lst.add(det);

   }
  }
 }

 //acá es donde estoy tratando de sacar los elementos del ArrayList para agregarlos a las celdas correspondientes y no he podido, si alguien me puede ayudar muchas gracias u otra forma mejor de hacero
 for (int n = 0; n < lst.size(); n++) {

  row = sheet.createRow(n);
  cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("");
  cell = row.createCell(2);
  cell.setCellValue("");
  cell = row.createCell(3);
  cell.setCellValue("");
  cell = row.createCell(4);
  cell.setCellValue("");
  cell = row.createCell(5);
  cell.setCellValue("");
  cell = row.createCell(6);
  cell.setCellValue("");

 }

 cell.setCellValue(res.getString("Horas_registradas_en_jira"));
 cell.setCellValue(res.getDouble("Horas_laboradas_sin_extras_y_sin_novedades"));

 try {
  String ex = "ensayo";

  try (FileOutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream("E:/copia/" + ex + ".xlsx")) {
   wb.write(archivo);
   archivo.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu problema en este punto es que no estás recorriendo adecuadamente las filas para armar una tabla en Excel.

> NOTA: ten en cuenta que las posiciones en Excel no empiezan en cero, sino en 1.
>
> [Fuente](https://coderwall.com/p/app3ya/read-excel-file-in-c)

Este es un pequeño pseudo-código que puedes adaptar para armar correctamente la información en tu archivo Excel:

```
// Aquí asumo que "Jira.size()" son la cantidad de datos.
int cantidadFilas = Jira.size();

// En tu consulta MySQL "en el SELECT" estás usando 5 columnas.
int cantidadColumnas = 5;    
// Armar una tabla en Excel. Esto se hace
// recorriendo las columnas y las filas.
// El primer ciclo "for" recorre la cantidad de datos.
for (int i = 1; i < cantidadFilas; i++) {
    
    // Crear una nueva fila.
    row = sheet.createRow(i);
    
    // El siguiente ciclo "for" recorre las columnas.
    for (int j = 1; j < cantidadColumnas; j++) {
        
        // Aquí armas la celda en la columna y fila específica.
        cell = row.createCell(j);
        cell.setCellValue(Jira[i]);
    }
}
```